# how can i rotate text on video only without the video with ffmpeg commands

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to rotate the text only on the video
here is my code

```
-i '/Users/me-mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F4189FE6-50EA-40B4-AE0F-F19074EE1488/data/Containers/Data/Application/7C214A2B-440B-468F-85F4-AE74CC4EC509/tmp/.video/1687332725.289482_IMG_0136.MOV' -filter_complex 'crop=1181.25:2100.0:1089.375:0.0,            drawtext=
              text=Abdullah Muhammad
              :fontsize=30
              :x=300
              :y=600
              :box=1
              :boxborderw=20
              :boxcolor=Gold
              ' -preset ultrafast -y '/Users/me-mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F4189FE6-50EA-40B4-AE0F-F19074EE1488/data/Containers/Data/Application/7C214A2B-440B-468F-85F4-AE74CC4EC509/Library/Caches/1687332725.289482_IMG_0136_1689171861232.mp4'
```

what i have tried

```
-i '/Users/me-mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F4189FE6-50EA-40B4-AE0F-F19074EE1488/data/Containers/Data/Application/7C214A2B-440B-468F-85F4-AE74CC4EC509/tmp/.video/1687332725.289482_IMG_0136.MOV' -filter_complex 'crop=1181.25:2100.0:1089.375:0.0,            drawtext=
              text=Abdullah Muhammad
              :fontsize=30
              :x=300
              :y=600
              :box=1
              :boxborderw=20
        :boxcolor=Gold
        ,rotate=PI/6
              ' -preset ultrafast -y '/Users/me-mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F4189FE6-50EA-40B4-AE0F-F19074EE1488/data/Containers/Data/Application/7C214A2B-440B-468F-85F4-AE74CC4EC509/Library/Caches/1687332725.289482_IMG_0136_1689171861232.mp4'
```

expected result

> Text only to be rotated

actual result

> Text and video are rotated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

draw text on blank video, rotate, then overlay:

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "
[0]crop=1000:700:0:0[v];
color=black[c];
[c][v]scale2ref[t][v];
[t]setsar=1,
colorkey=black,
drawtext=text='Test Text':fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=300:y=600,
rotate=PI/6:c=black@0[t];
[v][t]overlay=shortest=1
" output.mp4
```